# Passing function to derive state through container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a container which currently is structured as follows:

```
// container.ts
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectItems } from './actions';
import { selectSelectedItems } from './selectors';
import component from './component';

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  selected: selectSelectedItems(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  select: selectItems,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

However, in this case, every instance of the component will update whenever the selection changes.

What I really need is a *function which derives state from the redux store* that can be called in certain event hooks for performance reasons. For example, I need to conditionally open a modal if they drop with any items selected. It would be implemented like this.

```
onDrop = () => {
  // if there are any selected at all,
  // open a modal for the user.
  const selected = this.props.getSelected();
  if (selected.length) {
    this.openMoveRequestModal();
  }
}
```

I can make it "work" through a pretty ugly method.

```
export default class ProductGrid extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  static contextTypes = { store: PropTypes.object };

  onDrop = () => {
    const state = this.context.store.getState();
    // do whatever here
  }
}
```

But *ideally*, I would just be able to pass through a function reference that would derive the state from my redux store.

Is it possible to pass a function which derives state through a `react-redux` container?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect. It does exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't think it does? It passes through data derived from state and leverages memoization, I don't think it gives me a _function to derive state_.

Comment: What about an example from this section https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument (the one with `expensiveSelector`)?

Answer (score 0):

Components don't normally have access to the entire store state, because that's bad for performance.  If you return the entire store state from your `mapState` function, the component will re-render on *every* dispatched action, not just when the data it really needs changes.

So, if your component needs access to a separate piece of the state to make additional decisions, you have two main choices:

- Extract that additional piece of info and return it in `mapState` along with the data the component actually needs to render
- Move that logic out into a thunk function, which has access to `getState`.

I recommend using a thunk.

Example:

```
function openModalIfSelected() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        const selected = selectSelectedItems(state);

        if(selected.length) {
            dispatch(openMoveRequestModal());
        }
    }
}

// later, in the component file

const actionCreators = {openModalIfSelected};

class ProductGrid extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* all the normal rendering stuff here */}
                <DropTarget onDrop={this.props.openModalIfSelected} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, actionCreators)(ProductGrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that **in all cases** that your component doesn't need to re-render when the selection changes, you can just tell React to skip re-renders if only the selection has changed:

```
export default class ProductGrid extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    selected: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    /* others... */
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    // If any props other than "selected" changed, re-render.
    // Otherwise, if no props or only "selected" changed, skip the render.
    const changedProps = getChangedProps(this.props, nextProps)
    changedProps.delete('selected')
    return changedProps.size > 0
  } 
}

function getChangedProps (currentProps, nextProps) {
  return new Set(
    Object.keys(currentProps)
      .filter(propName => currentProps[propName] !== nextProps[propName])
  )
}
```

`shouldComponentUpdate` is a mechanism for avoiding re-renders based on some condition (a property of props and state). If the function returns false, the component won't render until it gets new props or state -- at which point `shouldComponentUpdate` will be called again.

Performance is important when implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` because it is called on every potential render (i.e. whenever props or state change).